# Why is there slowdown on a high poly mesh in edit mode when all faces are hidden?

Tags: edit-mode, memory-management

I've been wondering this for years now, so I'm working on a high poly mesh and I've hidden all but 50,000 vertices, there's a fair bit of slowdown and I kind of get that but even if you hide everything it's all still so slow. Why is this and what can be done to help it? Do I need more RAM or just a quadro card?

Comment: Computer specs?

Comment: Got a 2gb (4 according to dxdiag? :S) GTX 770, 8GB ddr3 ram, amd a7700k @ 3.3ghz, 550W bronze PSU, 1920x1080 monitor

Comment: Strange, with my gaming desktop (roughly the same as yours) i Subsurf'd a icosphere 6 times, applied and go into edit mode and hid everything, and it also lags. So i suppose this confirms it's not your desktop(presumably) or your scene. Suppose this might be a job for the more professional users here, i'll give you an upvote, as i'm curious now too.

Comment: Thanks! I find it interesting that sculpting is no problem with so many polygons and that sculpting went through a big optimisation update around the time of 2.5 I believe